# UITableView Custom Footer Disappears

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have used a custom UITableView Footer, It works fine , but when I'm changing the cell height in heightForRowAtIndexPath the footer is gone.

EDIT:

I create the footer here

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    actStreamFooter = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"AcvitityStreamFooter" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    footerHeight = actStreamFooter.frame.size.height;

    UIButton *taptoLoad = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, actStreamFooter.frame.size.width, actStreamFooter.frame.size.height)];
    [taptoLoad addTarget:self action:@selector(tapToLoad) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [actStreamFooter addSubview:taptoLoad];

    if (section == 1) {
        return actStreamFooter;
    }
    else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

then when I call

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

because I need to update the row, because I have an expanding view inside each cell.

After changing the height the footer disappears I tried `[tableView reloadData]` it works the footer does not disappear but there is a glitch it flashes when reloading. I want to remove the glitch

Comment: Where exactly do u set the footer?

Comment: Are you calling `heightForRowAtIndexPath` directly by your code?

Comment: Side note - move the bulk of that code inside the `if` statement. Why run all of that code for every section if you only need it in one section?

Answer (score 0):

A new footer needs to be initialized and returned for each section. A `UIView` cannot be in the view heirarchy more than once.